# Holding static value inside of adapter

Tags: android, adapter

I've a `public static RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool viewPool;`
Does this variable hold possible memory leak issues? Or adapter somehow automatically clears all adapter variable instances when it's not needed and activity is destroyed?

Comment: The only thing that is recycled within an adapter are views. (Depending on your implementation). All static variables will obey java rules and the worst case scenario is that the garbage collector cleans your variable if needed

Comment: @TiagoDávila So for safety reasons, I should clear instance just before view is destroyed?

Comment: is it any asynchronous procedure? Or is it just a variable?